# Code works on Android and iOS - why can't I move it into a PCL?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I have a static class that uses

- System.IO.Path
- System.IO.Directory
- System.IO.File.

Currently, the class is in my iOS project and **unchanged** also in my Android project.

I created a PCL that targets Android and iOS only.

However, neither one of the namespaces is available.

I presume that is because iOS and Android alone are not suitable for a PCL profile and that's why Windows Store 8 or Silverlight 5 gets added and that removes the System.IO.* namespaces.

Is this working as designed? Is file linking my only chance in this case?

Comment: @Charles why remove Xamarin.Android and add Monodroid instead? They are synonyms.

Comment: Check the spelling of the tag I removed.  :)

Comment: Haha, sounds like a girl's name "Xamarion", the daughter of the geek. Thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for now this is the way it's supposed to work.  You can use something like my [PCL Storage library](http://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) to access the file system from a PCL, or you can simply use file linking.

As a side note, I'd recommend choosing Windows Store and .NET 4.5 along with the Xamarin targets.  That profile is going to give you more APIs than the one which targets Silverlight 5 which you get by default when you just choose Xamarin platforms in that dialog.

Comment: does your lib support Xamarin? In the description it says that support is planned if async/await is available. It's been there a while now.

Comment: @Krumelur It doesn't yet support Xamarin. It isn't that complicated to do- basically reuse the Desktop code for Xamarin platforms.  There's a pull request from onovotny which does this for Xamarin.iOS.  In any case I'm hoping to update it to officially support iOS and Android this month.

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.Path, System.IO.Directory and System.IO.File are partially supported in PCL profile EXCLUDING silverlight 5: WP8 + NET4.5 + Xamarin + iOS.

Path.Combine works perfectly in this targeted PCL.

Comment: I have .NET 4.5, WP8, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS and System.IO.* is not there.

Comment: That is true. But File and Directory are not available. Path.Combine() is the least of a problem.